# Maven dependencies between main and test

Tags: maven

I have a multi-module project with two modules:

1. exist-core
2. exist-testkit

exist-core has both `src/main/java` and `src/test/java`, whilst exist-testkit has just `src/main/java`.

There are dependencies between the two projects, but they are split between main and test, i.e.:

1. The classes in `exist-testkit/src/main/java` have a dependency on `exist-core/src/main/java`.
2. The classes in `exist-core/src/test/java` have a dependency on `exist-testkit/src/main/java`.

So the compilation order needs to be:

1. `exist-core/src/main/java`
2. `exist-testkit/src/main/java`
3. `exist-core/src/test/java`

However I cannot seem to get that far, as Maven reports:

```
[ERROR] [ERROR] The projects in the reactor contain a cyclic reference:
Edge between 'Vertex{label='org.exist-db:exist-testkit:4.6.0-SNAPSHOT'}'
and 'Vertex{label='org.exist-db:exist-core:4.6.0-SNAPSHOT'}'
introduces to cycle in the graph org.exist-db:exist-core:4.6.0-SNAPSHOT
--> org.exist db:exist-testkit:4.6.0-SNAPSHOT
--> org.exist-db:exist-core:4.6.0-SNAPSHOT @
```

My `exist-testkit/pom.xml` has:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.exist-db</groupId>
        <artifactId>exist-core</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Whilst my `exist-core/pom.xml` has:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.exist-db</groupId>
        <artifactId>exist-testkit</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Is it possible to convince Maven that there is not a cyclic dependency between the source folders? I would rather not have to refactor out interfaces into a 3rd module as that would be a large amount of work.

Comment: So first there is a cyclic dependency which you have described in first 2 points of your question. The question is why do you have a separate testkit module? And you wrote that it is a large amount of work to refactor out interfaces into a 3rd module? Maybe I misunderstand your structure wrong, but having a clean separate module which contains only the interfaces sounds to me very good cause so you have a separate `-api` module? That sounds like a very good separation of concerns approach.. Furthermore how much work: I would estimate 10-minutes maybe even less..? Isn't worth?

Comment: So the exist-testkit module contains things like JUnit class rules which will be used by both exist-core and other modules (which I have not yet mentioned) for tests. An example is, a JUnit classrule from exist-testkit to start and stop an eXist-db server; the server code is in exist-core/src/main/java

Comment: So this exists-testkit contains JUnit class rules and interfaces which are used by other modules. If I correctly understand the interfaces are the JUnit class rules? Furthermore if the code for start and stop of this server is in exist-core ? so this sounds like a kind of a integration test part...

Comment: Kind of. Definitely integration tests. So the JUnit rule is a concrete class in exist-testkit which can start and stop a server, however to do so it needs to use classes from exist-core/src/main/java. The problem is that exist-core/src/test/java also needs to use these JUnit rules.

Comment: so those classes needed to start/stop are candidates to be refactored out to a separate module which would solve the cycle dependency issue...also solves separation of concern...

Comment: Those classes that start or stop will still need to talk to exist-core though. So I am not clear how I can refactor this? e.g.
https://github.com/adamretter/exist/blob/refactor/maven-build-4.x.x/exist-core/src/main/java/org/exist/storage/BrokerPool.java
https://github.com/adamretter/exist/blob/refactor/maven-build-4.x.x/exist-testkit/src/main/java/org/exist/test/ExistEmbeddedServer.java#L121
https://github.com/adamretter/exist/blob/refactor/maven-build-4.x.x/exist-core/src/test/java/org/exist/storage/RemoveCollectionTest.java#L61

Answer (score 0):

It is a cyclic dependency between the modules, even if it is not on the level or source folders. Since Maven builds one module after another, your structure does not work. You cannot compile the main classes of the module core, then compile the main classes of the testkit and then run the tests for the module core because module builds cannot be split.

So essentially, you need to refactor. Furthermore, this will make the build and the dependencies easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned - you're facing circular dependency between your modules. This dependency should be eliminated. This is a problem not only for Maven, but also will be the source of accidental complexity, that should be avoided.

To remove circular dependency, I can see three approaches:

1) Introduce 3rd module, for example `exist-common`. Then your compilation order will be  `exist-common`, `exist-testkit` and then `exist-core`. However, as you mentioned this will require huge refactoring, that you don't want to make at least for now.

To make things clear, this is what transformation is assumed:

- Dependencies before refactoring:

```
            ---------->
exist-core               exist-testkit
            <----------
```

- Dependencies after refactoring:

```
exist-core     -------------------------->   
    |                                     exist-common
    ---------> exist-testkit  ---------->
```

2) Make one-directional dependency, so that `exist-core` will depend on `exist-testkit`.
However, this forces you to duplicate code between modules, that is not a sound idea.

3) Define your `exist-core` tests (currently under `exist-core/src/test/java`) as a separate module. So, you will have `exist-core-main` and `exists-core-test` modules. Then your compilation order will be: `exist-core-main`, `exist-testkit` and then `exist-core-test`.

The last approach has benefit, that you will just update maven configs and change directory structure. So there will be no need to perform serious refactoring. However, it makes the project structure look kind of inconsistent.

If you choose 3rd approach, you will need to do the following:

1. Move core tests to separate directory `exists-core-test` under project root.
2. Update your parent pom.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>your.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>your-artifact-id</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>exist-core-main</module>
        <module>exist-testkit</module>
        <module>exist-core-test</module>
        <!-- Other modules -->
    </modules>
    <!-- Other relevant configurations -->
</project>
```

3. Make your `exist-core-test` pom.xml something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>your.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>exist-core-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>your.group.id</groupId>
            <artifactId>exist-core-main</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>your.group.id</groupId>
            <artifactId>exist-testkit</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Other dependencies -->
    </dependencies>
    <!-- Other relevant configurations -->
</project>
```

Comment: I don't understand your suggested (1), how will introducing `exist-common` help? Dependencies would still be: `exist-textkit` -> `exist-common` -> `exist-core`, and `exist-core`->`exist-testkit`. So there would still be a cyclic path. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: If common code (interfaces & classes) are in common module, how come `exist-common` can depend on `exist-core`? (My expectation is that code is not duplicated and each module has it's own independent responsibility. So I don't get how this can happen: `exist-textkit` -> `exist-common` -> `exist-core`, and `exist-core`->`exist-testkit` )

Comment: So `exist-core` contains a database engine, which needs to be started and stopped for tests e.g. `exist-testkit`. I can't move the entire database engine into `exist-common`, otherwise there would be practically nothing left in `exist-core`.

Comment: Maybe it's better to allow `exist-core` test to manage db directly (without using `exist-testkit`) ? Also - why 3rd option is ruled out? For example, Spring Boot project uses separate module for [integration tests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-tests). So in similar way - there could be `exists-integration-tests` module. At the same time `exists-core` still can have unit-tests, that doesn't require starting/stoping engine.